# django timezone settings change does not affect model

Tags: python, django, shell, django-1.7

I have django 1.7.x project. I inserted new data via the shell as follows:

```
from polls.models import Question, Choice
from django.utils import timezone

q = Question(question_text = "What's new?", pub_date = timezone.now(), status = True)
q.save()
q.pub_date
```

However, I found that dates are set to UTC. Hence, in the project's settings I have changed timezone to be `TIME_ZONE = 'Africa/Cairo'`. However, updating a record from the project's shell via `manage shell` by `q.pub_date = timezone.now()` does not change the timezone of the record to the new one. It is less than my development's computer by two hours, the difference between Cairo timezone and UTC. What could I missed it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

> Note that `now()` will always return times in UTC regardless of the value of `TIME_ZONE`; you can use `localtime()` to convert to a time in the current time zone.

But note that Django always stores datetimes in UTC, so even if you convert it using `localtime()` it won't affect how the value is stored. So `q.pub_date` will either be in UTC or in a time zone defined in the database (not Django) settings.

But what matters is how the datetimes are presented to the user, and the way to control that is described in the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/).